# Manipulating XMLDocument Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I am trying to take an xml string from php page and updating some node values to it in jQuery. However, I cannot figure out how to manipulate the XMLDocument I get in jquery and then returning it back as xml string to the php page. ANy help is most welcome.

```
var test     = <?php echo json_encode($test_xml); ?>;
test         = test.replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/g, ''); // <config><exclude_days_of_week>0</exclude_days_of_week><exclude_days_of_week>1</exclude_days_of_week></config>
var test_xml = $.parseXML(test);//some error "not well formed" but doesn't stop code from running
var exclude_days_of_week = $(test_xml).find("exclude_days_of_week").text().toArray(); // [0] [6]
```

Then on saving,

```
$('#save_type').on('click', function() {
 $(appointment_view_xml).find('exclude_days_of_week').remove(); // doesn't work
  var new_exclude_days_of_week = $("#working_days_of_week li:not('.working_day')").map(function(i, v) {
    $(appointment_view_xml).find('config').append('<exclude_days_of_week>' + v.value + '</exclude_days_of_week>');
    return v.value;
  }).get();

  return $(appointment_view_xml); // doesn't work too
});
```